# In ListView, how to prevent default list-item tap (nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

I've got a ListView with nested items - some have buttons on them.

When I tap on a button, the button callback fires but also the list-item action - which expands and shows the children.

How can I prevent that?

If a button is tapped, I just want the button callback.

If non button area of the list-item is tapped, I want the default children items expansion.

Comment: which version of {NS} and platform? are you working with Angular flavor?

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I think this is the default behaviour now. See [this playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=g7rmbM&v=3), sorry for not having proper expanding row :)